# XUL - Access to image information

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I trying to figure out how to write a Firefox extension that would give image information when i right-click on the image. Basically, I want image path when user right-clicks on the image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XUL

check out the tutorial for menus and popup guides

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/PopupGuide

from here then look at looking at the DOM and pick the element of interest in this case the image and happy days

Good luck